# Postgresql - omitting groups on a derived type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which correctly does not return a row if it matches the sum condition... however the problem is I need to change it.

I need it to now not return the GROUP if all grade totals have been met.

So for example I have data like below returned. Currently if A101 has enough occurrences it will not select that row. However what if I want all A1's unless all A1## values have met the SQL's condition?

My only thought is to run ANOTHER query to get the below results and then try and select based on that? But there must be an easier and faster way.

A101 THiS grade

A102 This grade

A103 THis grade

A201 this grade

A203 this grade

A204 this grade

B101 this grade

```
    RETURN QUERY            
        SELECT comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description,
   (sum(CASE WHEN crs.grade = 'Pass' THEN 1 WHEN crs.grade = 'Fail' THEN -1        WHEN crs.grade = 'Exceeds' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) >= comp_l.competency_break_level) AS reached_limit
FROM competencies comp
JOIN competency_levels comp_l USING (competency_group)
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT competency_id, review_status_id
 FROM call_competency
 JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
 WHERE email = _studentemail
) call_c ON call_c.competency_id = comp.id
LEFT JOIN competency_review_status crs ON crs.id = call_c.review_status_id
GROUP BY comp.id, comp.shortname, comp.description,       comp_l.competency_break_level
ORDER BY comp.id;
```

Comment: Please supply sample data and expected results, along with a query that can run against that sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Craig. Here is an output of our DB on my dropbox. I hope it is fine to link here and for you to get. I outputted what of our test data is in here.

Also as for expected results, it is 5 columns, with each A101 item and the last column being a count of how many times it was encountered

like this link showing my pic of the above query being run.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vm8wm52z4g027kt/Screenshot%202015-08-26%2017.14.28.png?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/q31qhowgm4dn7sv/PMADB.xls?dl=0